# How to get passphrase from a private key?

Tags: client

I have private key. How can I get passphrase for my bitcoin address.

Comment: What do you mean by "passphrase for your bitcoin address"? Addresses are not encrypted or password protected. Do you mean you have an encrypted copy of your private key (e.g. in an encrypted backup)? Or do you have a private key and you just want the corresponding address?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a symmetrically encrypted copy of your private key, where the encryption key was derived from a passphrase, you would be trying to perform a [known-plaintext attack](http://Known-plaintext%20attack). However, it should not be possible in polynomial time for a proper AES implementation, so I'm afraid you're out of luck.